# Visually show lists - indent after line break in bbEdit

Tags: bbedit

I am using bbedit 12 in a markdown document.

I have enabled **Soft Wrap Text at Page Guide** as it makes the document easier to read.

As can be expected, itemised lists looks like this:

```
* some reallllllly long 
text
* and another loooooong  
paragraph
```

but I would like them to be shown as follow:

```
* some reallllllly long 
  text
* and another loooooong  
  paragraph
```

Is there a setting to indent the lines in one item **on the display**?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image: bbedit screenshot showing reverse line indentation option]

The Reverse option for soft-wrapped line indentation seems to work for me. But I don't completely understand how it operates, so it may not work in all cases.